# Returning a C string in a DLL method

Tags: c, dll

I am trying to create a C-style DLL interface that takes in an input char * and assigns an output char * after performing some translation operation. The return value of the function is an error code, so it won't be used to return a char *.

I call the function in this manner:

```
char* output;
myfunc((char *) input.c_str(), &output);
```

And the function is defined as:

```
DLL_EXPORT int myfunc(char* input, char** output)
{
    string translation = translate(input);
    *output = (char *) malloc((translation.length()+1)*sizeof(char));
    strcpy(*output,(char *) translation.c_str());
}
```

Is this a correct way of implementing this? Am I creating a memory leak?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's correct, but you also need to provide another DLL function that will free the memory.  You cannot assume that the executable which has loaded your DLL is using the same version of the C runtime library, so if it tries to call `free` on the returned memory, you might end up corrupting your heap due to differences in the `malloc`/`free` implementations in the different runtimes.

Your API should look something like this:

```
DLL_EXPORT int myfunc(char* input, char** output)
{
    ...
    *output = malloc(...);
    ...
}

DLL_EXPORT void myfunc_free(char *output)
{
    free(output);
}
```

See also [allocating and freeing memory across module boundaries](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2006/09/15/755966.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Never assume you will use the same heap space from calling app and dll. In this case you must use [Windows Shared Memory object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686958%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: Huh?  Sharing memory between multiple processes loading the same DLL has nothing to do with a potential memory leak within one process.

Comment: @Adam Rosenfield who said anything about multiple processes?? Do you assume its safe to do memory allocation in dll and then use it in the process? Ever tried that with injection DLL's?

Comment: The first sentence in your linked article: "The following example demonstrates how the DLL entry-point function can use a file-mapping object to set up memory that can be **shared by processes that load the DLL**" (emphasis mine).  Yes, it's completely safe to allocate memory in a DLL and *use* it in the process.  Why would it not be?  The danger is when you try to *deallocate* memory in one module that was allocated by a different module, see the article I linked to.  What does DLL injection have to do with this?